# Quake 3 Team Arena won't start without restarting Steam

Tags: quake-3

I have Quake 3 Team Arena installed on Windows 7 32 bit via Steam and whenever I start up Steam and go to play it, it'll boot up just fine. If I play another game on Steam beforehand and then go to play Quake 3 it won't start up. If I restart Steam I can play Quake 3 again. What is going on here?

**EDIT:**

This happens with Quake 3 Arena as well. That should come as no surprise...

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a process of the last game you played still running in Task Manager processes tab. Killing them should make the problem go.

Comment: the process is usually "q3arena.exe"